# How to use ROS to control mobile Lego Mindstorms robots? (was: ROS on Lego NXT over Wifi)

Tags: ros, wifi, nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

has anybody successfully connected to a NXT using ROS (e.g. nxt_lejos or nxt_ros) over remotely?

Which hardware did you use? How much effort did you put into making it work?

Best regards,

Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36902/how-to-use-ros-to-control-mobile-lego-mindstorms-robots?-(was:-ros-on-lego-nxt-over-wifi)/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I have no personal experience with those sensors/blocks, I can say that `nxt_ros` only supports the 'standard' sensors/motors that come with the NXT set. Anything else will require you to add support. In theory however, using wifi would allow for (much) higher data rates and ranges. Of course you are still limited to what the brick can do, CPU wise.

The example shown [here](http://dexterindustries.com/blog/2011/11/07/wifi-week-communicating-with-computers/) on the Dexter Industries blog looks promising: the 'only' thing for you to do would be to write a kind of 'proxy', akin to [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial) and `nxt_ros` itself actually (which is also a proxy). Perhaps `nxt_ros` could be extended to include support for such a setup.

---

what I've done in the past is to create a movable 'base' out of Legos, with a laptop / netbook on top. This allows the laptop to function as a wifi-bridge, alleviating the range problem. Bandwidth is still limited, as USB is still used.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0